# Connection string. Cannot implicitly convert 'String' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I'm getting that error in title.

For my

```
cmd.Connection = Conn;
```

I have this

```
 public string Conn = connection.getConnection();
```

I'm using a windows application, how do I fix this?

Here is my complete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Room : Form
    {
        public SqlDataReader re;
        public string Conn = connection.getConnection();

        public Room()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Room_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          ..
          ..
          ..
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0 && textBox2.Text.Length != 0)
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = Conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "insertToRoom";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room_name", textBox1);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room_rate", textBox2);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all the textbox.", "Wrong Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is you trying to a database connection to a string. That is not going to work. A connection is made to the sql server and one piece of that is the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. First get the connection string from web.conf or app.conf and then create a sqlconnection to assign to sqlcommand.

```
 var connectionString =  
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameofConstringFromWebconfig"].ConnectionString;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.Connection =new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: I've already created a connection.cs, i don't know but I'll give you what is inside

Comment: static string con = "Password = xxx ; User ID = yyy ; Initial Catalog=zzzzz ; Data Source=ccccc";

        public SqlCommand string getConnection()
        {
            return con;
        }

Comment: Don't hard code your connection string. The best approach is in the config like suggested here.

Comment: SIR! Thank you for responding! I'm so dead right now. What will I input in the ["NameofConstringFromWebconfig"] and what will I put on the header code?

Comment: You would need to include a reference to System.Configuration. Then you need to add the connection string to your config file. You can use whatever name you want. I would recommend something like the database name or something to give you some insight about which connection it is since you can have more than 1 connection string in your config if needed.

Comment: Yeah i get what you are saying. But where will I put the code as stated from the answer?

Comment: Replace this line "cmd.Connection = Conn;" with the three lines above. You should also get rid of the Conn string in this class.

Comment: Hey it's turning great! But it said that the ConfigurationManager does not exist. How will i declare that?